# Error al descargar archivos de awesome table

Tags: excel, csv, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-sites

Buenas noches;

Escribo para consultar si el error es por el explorador o es común en estos casos. Estoy desarrollando una vista utilizando awesome table view, la cual permite interactuar googlesite con googlesheets y permite descargar los filtros con un boton csv, al descargar una búsqueda me tira un error en el excel ya que combina todas las celdas de la tabla del site  en 1 sola en excel ..alguna ayuda posible en esto..adjunto el problema al descargar.

[image]

Comment: Te está creando justamente eso, un CSV, es decir, un archivo separado por comas (**C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues). Si quieres abrirlo en Excel o en Google Sheets tendrás indicar al momento de la apertura, que es un **tipo** de archivo csv, entonces lo leerá y te lo mostrará como lo quieres, convirtiendo cada valor separado por comas en una columna.

Answer (score 0):

No se trata de un error.

Seguramente estás abriendo el archivo haciendo doble clic. En lugar de hacerlo así, abre primero Excel, crea un nuevo archivo e importa el archivo de valores separados por comas (CSV).

Los detalles están en la ayuda de Excel: [Importar o exportar archivos de texto (.txt o .csv)](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Importar-o-exportar-archivos-de-texto-txt-o-csv-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba)

Si deseas usar Hojas de Cálculo de Google, las instrucciones se encuentran en [Importar conjuntos de datos y hojas de cálculo](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es)